dynamic child pipeline not created and reports error Resulting pipeline would have been empty
I am trying to implement dynamic child pipelines for merge requests. However, the pipeline keeps failing with the error:

Failed - (Downstream pipeline can not be created, The resulting pipeline would have been empty. Review the rules configuration for the relevant jobs.)

My code is available here
Note: I am just trying to make the feature work so currently just copying an existing yaml file. Once the child pipelines feature work for me, the .gitlab/generated-config.yml file will be generated by a script.
Here is the configuration
# .gitlab-ci.yml
generate-config:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cp .gitlab/child-pipeline-template.yml .gitlab/generated-config.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .gitlab/generated-config.yml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"


child-pipeline:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - generate-config
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: .gitlab/generated-config.yml
        job: generate-config
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"


# .gitlab/child-pipeline-template.yml
job1:
  script:
    - echo job1

job2:
  script:
    - echo job2



I dug further and found this:

If the parent pipeline is a merge request pipeline,
the child pipeline must use workflow:rules or rules to ensure the jobs run.
If no jobs in the child pipeline can run due to missing or incorrect rules configuration:

Adding following rules section to the jobs fixes my issue (This is because I need the child pipelines to run on a merge request only):
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

